# Populating 2 dropdown list in dynamic datatable based on Mysql Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, dropdown

Good Day
Happy new year 2018.
I have **datatable** that contains **2 dropdown lists L1 and L2** and other text Fields.

*What I want to do is : when I click on an EDIT link, I can change the values in dropdown list L1 and according to the values in L1, I got a list in L2 and select one option from it.*

The values of the first list "L1" are retreived from Mysql Database and this works fine.
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mtGo.png)
the second list L2 should be filled in with values from another Mysql Table according to the value selected from the first list L1.
Unfortunately, the second List is not filled in after selecting value from the first list L1.
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z7i1.png)

To be sure that there is no problem in linking the First List to the second one , I tried to add manually the items ( the same items that are in Mysql table ) to the list L1 and when I select a value, the second list L2 works fine.
[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CVnQ.png)

This is the code of the function EDIT :

```
function editRow(oTable, nRow) {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
        jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + aData[0] + '">';
        jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<select id="L1" class="form-control" value="' + aData[1] + '" ><option value="0">- Select -</option><option value="1">Finance</option><option value="2">IT</option><option value="3">Marketing</option><option value="4">Operational</option><option value="5">Sales</option><option value="6">Staff</option></select>';
        jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<select id="L2" class="form-control" value="' + aData[2] + '" ></select>';

        jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<a class="save-row" href="">Enregistrer</a>';
        jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<a class="cancel-row" href="">Annuler</a>';

        $("#L2").change(function(){
            var deptid = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'getUsers.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {depart:deptid},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){

                    var len = response.length;

                    $("#L2").empty();
                    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                        var id = response[i]['id'];
                        var name = response[i]['name'];

                        $("#L2").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");

                    }
                }
            });
        });


    }
```

Hope someone could help me :( Thank you

Comment: Change `$("#L2").change(...)` to `$("#L1").change(...)`. You're also setting value of `select` element incorrectly.